# Как можно облегчить репозиторий?

Tags: git

Я бы хотел почистить реп, чтобы освободить место. Не нашел в инете инфу, но у меня в голове такой порядок действий.

1. Сделать новую ветку
2. Залить туда фулл проект
3. Удалить все ветки, кроме новой
4. Почистить историю репа и сделать коммит с мигрейтом проекта - стартовым

По итогу получаю чистый реп. Люди, которые работают с репозиторием -в пассивном режиме подкачивают этот коммит и все найс.

Есть ли инструменты для такой манипуляции?

Удалить реп и залить заново - плохой поинт и не стоит того.

P.S. В идеале, хотелось бы найти функцию - мол, чтобы не пушить еще раз весь проект, которая делает из мастер ветки - фулл версию проекта. ЧТобы избавиться от коммитов где тестился функционал, обновлялся сторонний софт и т.д.

Реп весил 100 гб. После создания нового - вес опустился до 30. Сейчас на новом репе уже обновили wwise и прилетели лишние 10 ГБ ,которые можно убрать, в теории.

Comment: так может Вы и бинарники/артефакты коммитите?

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема? В истории плохих комитов? Если да то rebase - i убираете все грязные комиты и готово. Если большое расхождение то можно и - - force добавить в слиянию, что бы все переписать.

Comment: Проблема в занимаемом месте. Я бы хотел просто убрать лишние байты

Comment: если коммитить все подряд (отладочные файлы, бинарники, непожатое видео), то конечно оно будет большим.

Comment: Да, это понятно, поэтому я хочу узнать, можно ли как-то без пересоздавания репа - оставить в одной ветке проект целиком, а остальное удалить

Comment: Очистка коммитов ничем не будет отличаться от удаления репы и заливания с нуля

Answer (score 0):

Вот [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102849/2231972) оставить только один комит с текущим состоянием и удалить всю историю (сделайте только резервную копию перед началом экспериментов).

```
git checkout master
git checkout --orphan newBranch    # создаем временную ветку
git add -A                         # добавляем в него все файлы
git commit                         # комитим
git branch -D master               # удаляем master
git branch -m master               # переименовываем текущую ветку в master
git push -f origin master          # делаем force push чтоб перезаписать master в origin
git gc --aggressive --prune=all    # чистим старые комиты
```

Эту операцию нужно повторить для всех веток.

Нужно понимать, что:

1. Тут я предполагаю, что главный бранч называется `master` и его состояние мы хотим сохранить. Другие ветки останутся и все файлы и версии доступные на тех ветках не будут удалены. Нужно другие ветки поудалять отдельно локально (`git branch -D <branch_name>`) и в remote репозитории (`git push origin --delete <branch_name>`).
2. теги ссылаются на комиты и если их не удалить, они точно также будут "держать" файлы. Нужно их поудалять локально (`git tag -d <tag_name>`) и в remote репозитории (`git push --delete origin <tag_name>`)

Comment: но смысл тогда в системе контроля версий...

Comment: @KoVadim согласен, что если делать это регулярно, то смысла в СКВ нет. Я понимаю вопрос в текущей его форме так, что хочется удалить всю историю. Это бывает полезно и это ответ на такой вопрос. Как не допустить разрастания репозитория, какие тут лучшие практики - это важно и нужно (и, вероятно, то, что автору пригодится и на самом деле нужно сделать), но это не то, о чем вопрос в его текущей формулировке.

Comment: возможно, но я не знаю, что там у автора в репозитории.